# React-FontAwesome unicode values in svg circle

Tags: reactjs, svg, unicode, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I am trying to embed a font awesome icon inside svg circles via unicode values from the font awesome website inside `<text>`, but they fail to appear:

[image]

for some reason which I don't understand, when I am using this unicode value(`&#x2713`) it does appear(but it's not the icon I need):

[image]

Some code:

from the react component:

```
       <g>
            <circle className="circle test-circle"
                key={index}
                cx={xScale(node.x)}
                cy={yScale(node.y)}
                r={node.r}
                fill={node.done === true ? colour : "grey"}
            />
            {node.done === true ? 
                <text id="chk" style={{fontFamily:'Font Awesome'}} x={xScale(node.x)-10} y={yScale(node.y)+10}>&#xf00c;</text>
                :
                <text id="chk" style={{fontFamily:'Font Awesome'}} x={xScale(node.x)-10} y={yScale(node.y)+10}>&#xf00c;</text>
            }

        </g>
```

from the scss:

```
text#chk {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome';
    content: "\f00c";
    font-size: 30px; 
}
```

What can cause this?

Comment: I am sorry for a dummy comment, but may be you use cdn with an old fontawesome lib, or fonts there doesn't have it. Try to save the document with the code in unicode encoding too.

Comment: All I did was downloading react-fontawesome npm packages. How do I use newer fa cdn's?

Comment: I am new to React. Instead of NPM package (probably it doesn't have new icons) try to import files directly from the fontawesome's CDN or download it and import manually from fontawesome.io (it is an archive with css and fonts, so just import them to your project and use, may be it will help)

Comment: I think you haven't import ```font-awesome.css``` or ```font-awesome.scss``` into your project.

Comment: @TienDuong I don't even have access to it, it does not come with the npm packages. how do I import it manually?

Comment: What is your fontawesome version?

Comment: @TienDuong 4.7.0. I tried to include the cdn URL in `index.html` and also import it on `index.js` after downloading another npm package. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, font family is `font-family='fontawesome'` and not `'Font Awesome'`